# Parse Stackoverflow RSS job feed for same name elements, with Feedparser in Python

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

Every job item on the Stackoverflow RSS feed has certain tags, with the key "category".

Looking basically like this:

```
<category>scala</category>
<category>hadoop</category>
<category>apache-spark</category>
<category>hive</category>
<category>json</category>
```

I would like to use Feedparser, to put all tags into a list. Instead I always get just the first element. The Feedparser documentation mentioned [entries[i].content](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry-content.html?highlight=entries), but I am unsure if that's the right approach, or how to use it in this case.

Here is my code:

```
import feedparser

rss_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed"
feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)
items = feed["items"]

for item in items:
    title = item["title"]
    try:
        tags = []
        tags.append(item["category"])
        print(title + " " + str(tags))
    except:
        print("Failed")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`category` on feedparser items is basically an alias for the first element in the `tags` list, which is basically a list of more feedparser items, each with a `term` attribute that contains the tag name.

You can just access the terms directly:

```
categories = [t.term for t in item.get('tags', [])]
```

For your code that is:

```
for item in items:
    title = item["title"]
    categories = [t.term for t in item.get('tags', [])]
    print(title, ', '.join(categories))
```

See the [`entries[i].tags` documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry-tags.html).